# Three.js Loaders

Tags: javascript, web, three.js, loader

I got the package file `three.js-dev` from threejs.org which I', trying to use like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./build/three.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./src/loaders/JSONLoader.js"></script>

<script src="./examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="./examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
```

But in I got an error in the console:

> [JSONLoader.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ral5s.png)

other error at source tab.

> [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyTZB.png)

I thought, is there issues about 'javascript import'?

So I searched it, and [found this at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and I replaced `'./Loader'` by `"./Loader"` but the error remains.

Is anyone who have wonder wisdom about this issue? Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the source of the `JSONLoader`. This is written in ES6 using a modules pattern (which is what the `import` token is for), that is bundled into the `build/three.js` that you are referencing already. The problem arises as it's not possible to use modules in the browser (..yet).

Simply put, you do not need to reference `/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js`, the JSONLoader is included by default.

See here:
http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=json#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader

Comment: Ah so it will be cleared about that error if I do not reference /src/loaders/JSONLoader.js?

Comment: Yes, the error will go away.. but the only way to really know is to try it ;) The `build/three.js` pretty much contains everything in the `src/` folder so you do not need to reference each part of three separately.. just the one file.

Comment: Thank you and Thank you!